# How to create new kind of entity/commit new endpoint in Google App Engine (Datastore)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-datastore

I was searching internet for some days and can't find any idea why I can't create second kind of entities (only Registration, Login don't work). I follow this tutorial ([link to tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints)) and everything goes well, until this moment. I create new LoginRecord, LoginEndpoint, declare it in web.xml (everything like Registration Record and Endpoint), but it don't work. I don't even see my URI in Dev Console. Any suggestion what could I missed?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.taminni.mieszkanko.backend.LoginEndpoint,
            com.example.taminni.mieszkanko.backend.RegistrationEndpoint,
            com.example.taminni.mieszkanko.backend.MessagingEndpoint
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

In Dev Console>Compute>Dashboard>CurrentLoad I have:

```
"/_ah/spi/com.example.taminni.mieszkanko.backend.Registration"
```

but the line for Login doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I find my mistake.
I don't write ".execute()" in:

```
logService.createUser("a","a").execute();
```

I expected that it will be something trivial , because in theory everything was correctly built... remember about mechanical mistakes!